# is there a way to change the background image of individual workspaces on Gnome Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

On Gnome changing the background image changes it for all workspaces. I want to have different images for each workspace.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity.

Comment: By Gnome, you don't mean GNOME Shell, do you? You're talking about Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Install Gnome Tweak Tool and Disable show desktop. 
After this, desktop menu and icons will disappear.
Using Software Center or this command in terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) to install gnome-tweak-tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Launch it(Advance Settings), turn off “Have file manager handle the desktop”

Install CompizConfig-Settings-Manager using software center or commands below

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

Launch CCSM, enable Wallpaper plugin and click to go into its configuration window. Click New to add 4 wallpapers one by one.

[Source](http://ubuntuguide.net/different-wallpapers-each-workspace-ubuntu-12-04)